# Intellij doesn't recognize angular modules, html elements, pipes, and so on

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

I'm having a problem getting angular language support running with a project that uses webpack (not sure if that's important, but without webpack everything works fine in intellij), and which is a multi module project consisting of java and an angular app.

The problem is that none of angular's modules are recognized

[image]

Says RouterModule is not an angular module.

[image]

No directive is matched for *ngFor and unresolved pipe async.

[image]

Though MatAutocompleteModule is correctly imported.

---

I've imported BrowserModule, CommonModule, and the project works perfectly fine. It's just intellij's detection that doesn't work.

I've installed @angular/language-service via npm. I've restarted the IDE (so many times).

What can I do to get this working?

dependencies (angular)

```
"@angular/animations": "~7.2.14",
"@angular/cdk": "~7.3.7",
"@angular/common": "~7.2.14",
"@angular/compiler": "~7.2.14",
"@angular/core": "~7.2.14",
"@angular/forms": "~7.2.14",
"@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.14",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.14",
"@angular/router": "~7.2.14",
```

devDependencies (angular related)

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
"@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.13.0",
"@angular/cli": "7.3.4",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "7.2.14",
"@ngtools/webpack": "7.3.4",
"@angular/language-service": "^7.2.14",
"angular-router-loader": "0.8.5",
"angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
"typescript": "3.2.4",
```

Comment: do you have all npm modules installed and included in index? also, does the issue persist after caches invalidation (**File | invalidate caches, Invalidate and restart**)?

Comment: Yes I have invalidated caches, I've listed the installed dependencies above @lena, do you see anything missing?

Comment: everything looks right at first glance... unfortunately it's nearly impossible to track down the issue without the project:(

Comment: Yeah, thought so already @lena. It's a jhipster application, a generated microservice gateway using jhipster 6.0.0 beta. I'm using intellij for years and searched for every setting, but nothing helped. I've since started to pull the frontend out of the generated app, and it's again working.

Comment: @chrispbacon did you find a solution to this? I recently upgraded from 2018.2 to 2019.2 and am running into the same issues

Comment: @rhavelka No I haven't. I started a new project and it worked

Comment: @lena I found a solution, before I had my node_modules marked as excluded. Once I mark it as a normal directory, everything works. but the thing is I don't want to have node_modules included since it generates a lot of noise when I'm searching for a snippet of code within my project.

Comment: @rhavelka Also indexing will take ages

Comment: normally the IDE auto-excludes `node_modules`, but adds direct dependencies to javascript libraries, so that the completion, etc. is available. You must have overwritten the default behavior by removing the library and excluding (and then including back) everything

Answer (score 31):

I am going to give an answer for what worked for me (with help of jetbrains support). When upgrading from intellij 2018 to 2019, your `node_modules/` directory cannot be excluded from your project, if it is then intellij will have trouble indexing your project.

When the `node_modules/` directory is created, it will automatically be assigned to a status of *library root* and should not be messed with, otherwise intellij will start treating it as a normal directory within your project. If you do fiddle with it, remove the `.idea/` directory and re open the project by doing **File** > **Open** > **my-app**.

If you experience slow indexing after performing an `npm install`, remov the `.idea/` directory and opening your project again should fix the issue.

Comment: Worked for me with IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.X. Voted. Thank you.

Comment: With WebStorm there's also a bit of a caveat w.r.t. recognizing libs, be sure to let WebStorm index `node_modules` as a `library root` before you `exclude` it (if that your thing). Also watch out to not forcefully `exclude` `angular.json` since this is the basis for the detection of Angular along with code styling/completion and so on.

Comment: Did not help with Intellij Ultimate 2021.2.3

Answer (score 14):

Had the same problem with IntelliJ 2019.3

But there is a simple solution: 
right click your `node_modules` directory -> mark directory as -> cancel exclusion

[image]

The directory should now be marked as `library root` and everything should be recognized.

Comment: My node_modules was markes as library root, however, going to RC -> mark dir as -> showed that dir was excluded. After removing it from excluded label with project name was applied and slow reindexing is going on right now. I hope it will help

Comment: Works for WebStorm 2021.1.2, but won't for Intellij 2020.3 in my case

Answer (score 9):

Simpler and tested on IntelliJ 2020:

1. delete `.idea` folder for frontend project
2. go to menu File -> "*Invalidate Cache / Restart...*" -> click "*invalidate cache and restart*"
3. Let IntelliJ re-index your projet, the problem should be fixed.

This solution should work on IntelliJ 2020 and after.

Comment: ah ! the nuke button!

Answer (score 8):

Same problem I faced with the Ionic 5 project.

The Modules are shown or highlighted as error and the HTML, Ionic tags are shown it's not a tag in Intellij Idea ultimate edition.

I follow the mentioned steps as:

1. First, delete the `.idea` folder from the project.
2. Close the IDE.
3. Remove the project from the shortcut lists (click on the close button).
4. Open via **Open -> path of the project ->**
5. It imports properly.
6. Hurray, Projects not shown a single error or highlighted.

Comment: Only solution that worked for Intellij 2021.

Comment: Also worked for me. Than you. This issue was really annoying.

Answer (score 3):

An update to Malimo's answer above ^.  In the latest version, you manipulate the "Excluded/Not Excluded" flag (here shown as "Excluded" which solved my problem).

This is what it looks like in v.2020.1:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately for me none of the above worked perse. I had to use a combination of them (**the order is important!**):

1. Invalidate cache/restart.
2. Delete the .idea folder
3. Restart Pycharm
4. Profit

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue while running IntelliJ IDEA version 2019.3.  I apparently needed to swap JetBrains accounts (from my old work account which was expired to my personal account which had an active license).  I downloaded the latest version which is 2021.3.2 and my issue is now resolved.

I believe that updating the latest Angular CLI (13.2.0) is what broke things.

Answer (score 0):

Actually nothing worked for me, so I had to uninstall and install it again without importing previous settings in new installation.

Comment: I confirm (that nothing worked). Will not reinstall. Will use VScode instead...

Comment: I confirm. Dont work for me. I tried all solutions

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem even in a newer version. the library I was using is "ngx-translate" and I had to add it via IntelliJ settings:

Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Libraries

PS: you can also unexclude it via right click on the project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tired all the steps listed (deleted `.idea`, delete `.angular`, delete `node_modules`) nothing worked.

Finally figured out to do this:

```
<button mat-button>Scan Barcode</button>
```

instead of this:

```
<mat-button>Scan Barcode</mat-button>
```