# Why Angular 12 build is breaking node_modules imports in WebStorm?

Tags: angular, npm, webstorm, node-modules

We have updated our app to the latest Angular 12 (ngrx 12, router latest, etc)...

Update finished pretty well, the app is building and is running good, except one thing...

`node_modules` imports are broken, resulting in all common Angular pipes, directives being not found:

```json
Unresolved pipe async
No directive is matched on attribute ngIf
Unknown html tag mat-spinner
```

Doing advices from [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55902681/intellij-doesnt-recognize-angular-modules-html-elements-pipes-and-so-on?rq=1) helps. If I delete node_modules/.idea paths and then reinstall and reindex files, WebStorm is able to resolve everything. **But !** Running `ng serve` breaks it all again and only full cycle (delete node_modules/.idea, reindex) helps.

Yes, WebStorm loses imports exactly during the build phase, I have rechecked a couple of times. It's good after deleting node_modules/reinstalling/reindexing, even multiple WebStorm restarts won't break anything, but running for just one time **`npm run proxy`** (simple *`ng serve`* script, you can find it below in package.json) breaks module imports completely - you need to do full delete/reindex to restore it.

Here is our **package.json**. Maybe something is wrong with package versions?

```json
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "proxy": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --disable-host-check --host 0.0.0.0 -c local",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.1.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.1.4",
    "@angular/common": "~12.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "~12.1.4",
    "@angular/elements": "~12.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.1.4",
    "@angular/localize": "^12.1.4",
    "@angular/material": "^12.1.4",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^12.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.4",
    "@angular/router": "~12.1.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^4.0.0",
    "@ngrx/data": "^12.3.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^12.3.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^12.3.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^12.3.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^12.3.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^12.3.0",
    "@ngu/carousel": "^3.0.1",
    "@sentry/angular": "^5.27.1",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^5.27.1",
    "@sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2": "^8.1.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^16.0.3",
    "@types/deep-equal": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/dompurify": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.157",
    "@yellowspot/ng-truncate": "^1.5.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "class-transformer": "^0.2.3",
    "class-validator": "^0.12.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "date-fns": "^2.12.0",
    "deep-equal": "^2.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-unicorn": "^28.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "material-icons": "^0.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^6.1.0",
    "ngx-dropzone": "^2.3.0",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^3.2.1",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^3.3.0",
    "ngx-scrollbar": "^7.5.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "sweetalert2": "^10.3.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.1.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.1.4",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^11.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.21.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

I am running my project with **`npm run proxy command`**

**Angular.json**

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "projector": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/projector",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/scss"
              ]
            },
            "scripts": [],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "lodash",
              "formiojs",
              "native-promise-only",
              "core-js",
              "jwt-decode",
              "fetch-ponyfill",
              "compare-versions",
              "moment-timezone/moment-timezone",
              "json-logic-js",
              "jstimezonedetect",
              "class-transformer",
              "validator",
              "ngx-dynamic-form-builder"
            ],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "4mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "8kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "local": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.local.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "local"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "projector:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "projector:build:production"
            },
            "local": {
              "browserTarget": "projector:build:local"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "projector:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "projector:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "projector:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "projector",
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@ngrx/schematics"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must be a problem with lazy-compiled Ivy packages; [similar issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-50675) is fixed in 2021.1.2. Please consider upgrading WebStorm to the latest version

Comment: updating to 2021.1.2 solves this for me. Ty