# HTML file error in Angular application in WebStorm

Tags: angular, npm, webstorm

I am getting the error shown below in WebStorm. It is a brand new project where I am just testing a form. It doesn't happen until I run `ng serve` (and `ng serve` gives no errors and runs the application just fine).

If I delete my node_modules folder and reinstalls using `npm install` then I get no errors again until I run the project (or restarts my IDE it seems). I even tried creating a new project but still the same error(s) occur.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?! It seems to only be happening to new projects I create as well.

[image]

EDIT:
Added image of module file (`app.module.ts`) I only have the one module.

[image]

EDIT 2: Component added as well.

[image]

Comment: Import the FormModule/ReactiveFormModule in the module were this component is declared.

Comment: I already did. And the project works just fine it is just the HTML file showing errors (and I have no typeahead of the form-specific attributes (eg. if I write "<form [fo" I don't get any suggestions of ...[formGroup] for instance after the errors are shown. But initially when creating the project everything is working fine. (Added the module file in the post above)

Comment: Try invalidating caches (File | Invalidate caches, Invalidate and restart) - does the issue persist?

Comment: The application is running fine right?

Comment: What is your IDE version?

Comment: @amnah Yes unfortunately the issue still persists after that. And yes the application works just fine other than that fine when running it in the browser. No errors when running ng serve or in the browser console for that matter.

Comment: @LazyOne it is 2020.3.2 as far as I can see.

Comment: @PNS Please try the latest **2021.2** version. I'm not using Angular myself (so cannot verify/test it)... *but for me* your issue seem to be related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68637509/783119 (ofc, I can be completely wrong here... but still worth checking the latest version)

Comment: @LazyOne That seemed to solve it! You have restored my faith in StackOverflow :) Thank you so much for your assistance, I have been knocking my head against the wall the whole day!

Comment: @PNS Let me know tomorrow / confirm that it definitely works after you will be using it for a while.

Comment: @LazyOne after several pc restarts and reruns of the program I can confirm that I still have had zero problems. I have not tried to install more packages with NPM, but I do not think that should have any impact anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the `formGroup` in your typescript file.

```
 descriptionForm= new FormGroup({
  firstName: new FormControl(''),
  lastName: new FormControl('')
 });
```

Comment: Sachin, I already have that (check newest edit). I tried your way of instantiating FormGroup as well but same result.